# Recursive find in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is there a recursive find function for a find in emacs? I thought the 'nix "find" was implemented in eshell but perhaps not (I've been using it on OS X but it must have been calling FreeBSD's "find")... I know of rgrep, find-grep, grep-find, in emacs, but I don't actually need the grepping part. Perhaps it's a feature in one of dired's functions (though I didn't find it)? Using windows and I miss some 'nix utilities... thought emacs 23.2 might fill in for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dired-find](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-and-Find.html)? It depends on the external command `find` though. There might be a lisp implementation of `find` somewhere, but you might be better off just getting the windows port of the 'nix utilities such as `find`. Try [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).

Comment: `find-dired` was it... thanks! (and I did have cygwin installed on that machine! forgot...)

Answer (score 1):

I use [`ifind.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/ifind.el).

Answer (score 1):

The [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) project works well for finding files in your project and instantly navigating to them.

Here are the commands: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#interactive-commands

In particular the one I use is `C-c p 4 f` which recursively searches your project to find a filename that matches the provided pattern. Works well, and easy install via `M-x list-packages`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that feature for a long time, and I am now totally happy with `projectile` (see my answer: [How do I find-file recursively in directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040160/how-do-i-find-file-recursively-in-directories/19857357#19857357))