# Quick file-open or file-find like sublime text, or even intelliJ

Tags: emacs, fuzzy-search, fuzzy

Is there a package or something built-in to emacs that will do fuzzy file name matching within a directory structure (that is a project directory) which mimics the quick-open in Sublime and Intellij.

I don't require that it popup a text input UI in the middle of the application with possible matches listed below in drop-down form, updating as I type.  Just that it match the intentions of that feature.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188058/is-there-a-quick-file-open-find-like-intellijs-find-file-or-sublimes-somethi

Comment: Duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656096/emacs-how-can-i-find-a-file-in-my-project-quickly

Comment: Not really an answer, but an interesting, fairly on topic video: https://vimeo.com/1013263

Answer (score 1):

I have only a vague idea of Sublime, but you might be looking for [Projectile's find-file](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) command. It also has the same to find inside a directory (not a project). It comes with various matching possibilities, with an `helm` interface with `helm-projectile`, which can be replaced by `ido`.

It is not buit-in though, you have to install it with the package manager, `package.el`: `M-x package-install RET projectile RET`, once it is [configured](http://stable.melpa.org/#/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) (e.g., `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`) to get fuzzy matching of filenames with `find-file` (<kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>):

```
(ido-mode t)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```