# Emacs command to Find and Open File similar to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, emacs

I've recently switched from using Eclipse to emacs. I'm trying to find a way to emulate eclipse's Ctrl-Shft-r functionality which lets you type in a file name and it begins showing all files in the current workspace that begin with the string you are typing.

C-x C-f seems to handle just tab-completion in the current directory, whereas Eclipse's functionality looked through all sub-directories to find matching files.

I'm looking for something (maybe there's a plugin that does this) that allows you to type the name of folder to look in, and then a partial file and returns back the results in a buffer. Possibly that uses auto-complete to list off matching files with their full paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, steer clear of vanilla `find-file` function (that's the interactive function that is run when you hit `C-x C-f`). It is very limited, it forces you to hit `TAB` all the time, and the first thing most people do when switching to emacs is replace `find-file` with something more powefull.

There're a number of alternatives. [ido-mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) is one, [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) is another. The former is light-weight, fast and comes built-in with emacs. The latter is immensely powerful and strives to be fast, too.

Second of all, there're two ways a recursive file search can usually be done:

1. directory search - that's when you just search a directory, no surprises here;
2. project search - that's when you setup a project your're working on, thus making emacs aware of which files are of interest to you right now.

For directory search, `ido-find-file` and `helm-find-file` are both viable options. Ido does its search automatically when you pause typing; helm uses `(C-u) M-g s` to activate grep. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040160/how-do-i-find-file-recursively-in-directories) for more info.

For project search, you need a library to manage your projects. [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) is great for that. Set it up and use `C-c p f` or `C-c p F` to list files in current or all of your projects, respectively. Oh, and projectile uses ido by default, but there [is](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) helm support, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't think of replacing commands so I'll look that up. I also realized since I'm using eclim it provides `eclim-file-locate` which I can use similar to eclipse's `ctrl-shift-r`.  The methods you've listed off work beyond just eclim support though so they'll help me in other areas.

Comment: FWIW: I would *not* say "*steer clear of vanilla `find-file`*". And I doubt that "*the first thing* ***most people*** *do when switching to emacs is to replace `find-file`*" - far from it. Otherwise, the answer is OK. FWIW: You can  get the same kind of "powerful", immediately-show-candidates behavior using [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles). (And you can also get complete-on-demand behavior, using `TAB`, which is ***not*** useless in the context of Emacs.) In Emacs there are many, many ways to skin a cat. And the default, out-of-the-box (vanilla) behavior of Emacs is not bad.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) which indexes your project's files. I used it for a while but have recently switched to using helm-recentf

```
(global-set-key "\C-x\ \C-r" 'helm-recentf)
```

I have recent files set to a large number. Pretty much anything I've ever opened is a few keystrokes away. This even doubles up as a handy way to switch buffers.

```
(require 'recentf)
(setq recentf-auto-cleanup 'never)
(recentf-mode 1)
(setq recentf-max-saved-items 200)
```